# Access node_module from different location

Tags: node.js, vue.js, gruntjs

So I'm setting up a project with Grunt + Grunt-Browserify + Vue + Vueify and I'm having problem accessing the 'vue' module.

This is my folder structure:

```
app/
   build/
   app.js
   app.vue

grunt/
     node_modules/
     Gruntfile.js
     packaje.json
```

This is the content of my **Gruntfile**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        browserify: {
            vendor: {
                src: ['../app/app.js'],
                dest: '../app/build/app.js',
                options: {
                    watch: true,
                    keepAlive: true,
                    browserifyOptions: {
                        debug: true
                    },
                    transform: ['vueify']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify']);
};
```

And this is the content of my **app.js**:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var App = require('./app.vue');

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement(App);
    }
});
```

When I run `grunt` I get **Cannot find module 'vue'**

if I set the variable `Vue` like this:

```
var Vue = require(__dirname + '/' + 'vue');
```

I get this error `Cannot find module 'vue-hot-reload-api'`

If I place my **app** folder inside the **grunt** folder on the same level as **node_modules** and variable `Vue` is set like this: `var Vue = require('vue');` everything works.

How can I make it work so that no matter where my application is located I can always locate a **module**.

Thank you and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the incorrect directory name and path:

```
src: ['../../vue-app/app.js']
```

Should it be

```
src: ['../app/app.js']
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo, it's like you said :) i editted the post